# Need help finding the right FFC connector

Tags: connector, ffc, fpc

This is my first time working with FFC/FPC. I'm looking for a FFC/FPC connector to match this [Micro SD card extender](http://bplus.com.tw/ExtenderBoard/B19%20V1.1.html), just like shown on the PCB.

According to the [dimensions diagram](http://bplus.com.tw/PDF/B19-DB19_dimension.pdf) the pitch seems to be 1 mm and FPC thickness is 0.33 mm. But according to [the schematic](http://bplus.com.tw/PDF/B19_V1_1_Schematic.pdf) the connector's seems to be 0.5 mm pitch.

I have also asked the manufacturer of this extender what connector they use and they've sent me the datasheet (mechanical drawing). Unfortunately the drawing is mostly in Chinese. [I have uploaded the datasheet here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05368363853466026427).

As shown in the connector's datasheet, the pitch is 0.5 mm, and it's meant for a FFC thickness of 0.3 mm (and not 0.33 mm).

All of this got me confused as how to choose a matching connector.
Is the FFC thickness critical ? Why do they use a 0.3 mm connector with an FFC 0.33 mm thick ?

I've been looking for the connector on digikey, it seems that I need a 0.3 - 0.33 mm FFC thickness connector, contacts on the bottom, 10 positions, 0.5 mm pitch, preferably with a "flip lock" mechanism. One of the parameters on digikey is the "Cable End Type" which can be either "Tabbed, Tapered" or "Straight, Tapered" - What does this parameter mean ? And which one do I need ?

[Link to digikey filtered search.](http://www.digikey.com/short/3m851c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you've been given is definitely inconsistent.

That said, 0.5mm pitch seems the most likely candidate as it:
a) matches the stated pitch in the schematic 
b) dimension D in the data sheet for the 10 way connector is 5.5mm which is what it says for the loom width in the manufacturer's diagram

The tolerance on the FPC width is +/- 0.05mm so any receptacle between 0.3mmm and 0.33mm should be fine

Your loom appears to be straight (no rounded corners)

Something like this should do: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0528921095/WM9203CT-ND/1089660

You should really get some samples before going too far into design/manufacturing.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about "Your loom appears to be straight (no rounded corners)" ?

Comment: A 'tapered' loom has round corners on the connector edge, a 'straight' loom has 90 degree corners. If you look at page 2 of the data sheet for the connector I linked to, you can see it will actually take both style looms.